# Able to open downloaded programs, but once closed need to download again

Tags: macos, dmg, gatekeeper

In particular, I'm trying to use Calibre for eBook management. Interestingly, this has never happened with any other app before, but when I   quit the app (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>), it's almost as if I never installed it in the first place.

Any insight into what is going on?

Comment: How are you launching Calibre after you install it?  What version Calibre and macOS?  In your title you mention "programs."  What other programs are you experiencing this with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running them from their DMG file, usually located in the folder where you set your downloads to go to.

Apps you want in your /Applications folder, you have to copy them there. That's why most DMGs provide Applications' alias in the DMG.

Use spotlight or  apps like [Easyfind](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to find the relevant installer.

Comment: spot on! I wasn't clear on this difference and why it might exist in the first place. Thank you